# button not displaying right side of the layout in android

Tags: android

Hi in this Layout i have two button's named as back and home same names i mentioned as id's for both.Now left side i want to display back button and right side corner i want to display home.But home button not displaying at the right corner.Now if i mention margin left it's not showing properly.Can any one please help me

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#FF0000" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"> 
          <Button
         android:id="@+id/back"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@drawable/back"
         />
 <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"

            />
         <Button
             android:id="@+id/home"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/home" 
             android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
             />  

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: there is "gravity" -and layout_gravity for linear layouts- flirt with them they will be of help to you..next time research or google your questions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/back" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/home" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/home"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use relative layout for that, see that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/account_settings" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/account_settings"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

if you want to do this with linear layout use weight sum

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/account_settings" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/account_settings" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/back"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/home"/>
</LinearLayout>
```